# Cycles GPU OpenCL render has square white artifacts and strange lines on an AMD RX 5700 XT in Blender 2.82

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, artifacts, opencl

**Issue:**

Rendering with my AMD GPU, either in GPU-only mode or GPU+CPU mode, causes artifacting (either strange black lines if GPU-only or white box artifacts of GPU+CPU) in OpenCL Cycles renders.

**GPU-only:**

[image]

**GPU-CPU:**

[image]

**Setup:**

[image]

[image]

To note, if I only use the CPU to render then the output is fine but that defeats the purpose of trying to reduce render times. The whole point of enabling GPU+CPU is to get the renders out as quickly as possible.

I've tried setting it to Supported and also tried Experimental. The output is the same in Cycles. Rendering in Eevee is fine and without issue.

**Eevee (which only uses GPU to render):**

[image]

**CPU-only Cycles:**

[image]

As can be seen above CPU-only and Eevee are fine, but not Cycles when GPU is in the mix for OpenCL. What are some things I can try or do to fix this? Any mention of artifacts/strange lines with AMD GPU's seems to be dated back in 2016 and extensive Google searches don't yield anything, so this clearly isn't an issue for most people now.

**My system specs:**

- OS: Windows 10 64bit version 1909
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 3950X
- GPU: PowerColor AMD RX 5700 XT 8GB
- RAM: 32GB DDR4 3600Mhz
- GPU Driver: Radeon Adrenalin 2020 edition 20.4.1 (released 23 April 2020)
- Blender: 2.82.7 (via Steam)